# How to get/set out-of-scope variables when testing a function with dependency on these (jest)?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to have full test coverage on some helper functions in my project. My first tests for either of the functions checks whether 2 out-of-scope variables are declared or not, which run successfully.

What I want to do is, **jest** to *set/mock* `wrapper` and `layer` variables declared out-of-scope of the functions to be tested, but can't seem to have it right no matter how hard I tried.

Thankful and appreciate any kind of help in this direction as I'm fairly rookie in terms of writing tests in general not to mention tests for **jest**.

1. I have tried `jest.mock` by mocking by default my imported module and then did `jest.requireActual` on 2 functions.
2. I have tried `jest.doMock` with a module factory which sets these 2 variables and then returns in an object.

Module: **helpers/index.js**

```js
let wrapper; // Is created on runtime ergo initially undefined.
const layer = document.createElement('div');
layer.classList.add('layer');

const isElement = elm => {
  if (!(elm instanceof Element)) {
    throw new Error('Given element is not of type Element or is undefined!');
  }
}

export const someFn = async () => {
  wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');

  isElement(wrapper);
  isElement(layer);
  
  // Code that needs to be tested
  // but cannot since when testing this function
  // 'wrapper' and 'layer' are always undefined.
}
```

Test: **helpers/index.test.js**

```js
// Helpers
import {someFn} from 'helpers';

describe('Method: someFn', () => {
  test('should NOT throw', async () => {
      await expect(someFn()).resolves.not.toThrow(); // but it does!
  });
});
```

*Actual result*: `Received promise rejected instead of resolved`

*Expected result*: Not to throw, considering these out-of-scope variables that this function relies on, can somehow be set/mocked while testing it.